# Convert xml data into binary data

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

How can i save xml data into binary field of data base table?

Comment: Which language are you using? Java? .Net? or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to reencode is as binary data? You should be able to save the XML data directly as raw data in the binary field. You'll have remember what character encoding you used when reloading the value if you're using a non-ascii character set.

Answer (score 0):

For Java, you could convert XML to fast infoset.  Glasfish has a [subproject](http://fi.java.net/) to do so.

Then it's just a matter of loading the result into a BLOB.

Comment: how can you answer so fast? First let us know which technology he wants to use then you can answer. Don't make guesses in answer or it may give you down votes.

Comment: You tell me that !  You just highjacked my answer on eclipse and tomcat if I remember correctly...  If you want we can share the day. 12 hours for you 12 for me.

Comment: I've not highjacked your answer. I just answered the question in comment in your answer. If you want you also do the same. Also when commenting here I actually even don't know that you are same who have answered in eclipse and tomcat question.

Comment: No prob Harry, let's carry on the game and hoard points.  In the process we learn so much. Have fun.